# How does the bitwise operator XOR ('^') work?

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

I'm a little confused when I see the output of following code:

```
$x = "a";
$y = "b";
$x ^= $y;
$y ^= $x;
$x ^= $y;
echo $x; //Got b
echo $y; //Got a
```

How does the operator `^` work here?

Comment: Answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249423/how-does-xor-variable-swapping-work

Comment: Are you asking how the operator works or how the swap works?

Comment: FYI: strings get truncated if they contain different number of characters

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like [swapping a value using XOR](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingValuesXOR). Though I am not sure about the strings in PHP (normally you use it for ints or something). For a truth table of XOR you can [look here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or#Truth_table).

The interesting thing about `XOR` is that it is reversable: A XOR B XOR B == A ... that is not working with `AND` or `OR`. Because of this fact, it can be used as in your example to swap two values:

```
$x ^= $y;
$y ^= $x;
$x ^= $y;
```

means:

```
$x = $x ^ $y
$y = $y ^ ($x ^ $y)                // = $x
$x = ($x ^ $y) ^ ($y ^ ($x ^ $y))  // = $y
```

Comment: PHP is dynamically typed and hates strings - it will convert them to int or double whenever an opportunity presents itself.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks for pointing this out - I didn't know it and just assumed that something like this happens ^^

Answer (score 24):

^ is the "exclusive or" bitwise operator. It reads in English as "either or". The result is 1 if and only if both bits differ:

```
1 ^ 0 = 1
1 ^ 1 = 0
0 ^ 0 = 0
```

Simplifying the example a bit so (and using Pseudo code):

```
$x = 0011 //binary
$y = 0010

$x = $x xor $y
//Result: x = 0001

//x = 0001
//y = 0010
$y = $y xor $x
//Result: y = 0011

//x = 0001
//y = 0011
$x = $x xor $y
//Result: x = 0010
```

All that PHP has done is treat the string "a" and "b" as their integer equivalents.

Answer (score 7):

In this example, when you're using ^ characters, they are casted to integers. So

```
"a" ^ "b"
```

is the same as:

```
ord("a") ^ ord ("b")
```

with one exception. In the first example, the result was casted back to a string. For example:

```
"a" ^ "6" == "W"
```

because of:

```
ord("a") ^ ord("6") == 87
```

and

```
chr(87) == "W"
```

Answer (score 6):

Th `^` operator is a bitwise operator, meaning that it operates on every bit of its operands.

It returns a value in which each bit is `1` if the two corresponding bits in the operands are unequal, and `0` if they're equal.

For example:

```
   100110110
 ^ 010001100   
 = 110111010
```

Comment: In the example code for the question the operands are *strings*. What actually happens? For instance, are the ASCII values used? What if strings are longer than one?

Answer (score 2):

The ^ operator performs an XOR on the bit values of each variable. XOR does the following:

```
a   = 1100
b   = 1010
xor = 0110
```

x is the result of the XOR operation. If the bits are equal the result is 0 if they are different the result is 1.

In your example the ^= performs XOR and assignment, and you swap the bits around between the two variables $x and $y.

Read more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor_swap_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

`XOR` or the exclusive or is based on logic and circuits. It indicates that, for example, `A ^= B` where A is 0111 and B is 0101 can be either 1 or 0 at each corresponding bit but not both. Therefore

```
A = 0111
B = 0101
    _____
^=  0010
```

To understand this better the rules of binary math apply except that there are no carry overs. So in binary math 1 + 0 = 1, 0 + 0 = 0, 0 + 1 = 1 and 1 + 1 = 0 (where a 1 is carried over to the next more significant position in binary math, but the XOR rules bypass this).

> Note: That the XOR rules, therefore, allow you to take the result of A
>   ^= B in the example above and add A to it to get B or add B to it to
>   get A (referencing the swap ability mentioned above.