# Converting uint to float in C++

Tags: c++, floating-point

I'm using ReadProcessMemory in order to get 4 bytes. The function allows me to represent this as an unsigned int. I wish to represent this as a float; or in other words use the byte representation of this uint for my float. I've tried casting and it does not seem to work.

Example:
byte representation:
94 4E 2D 43

uint:
1127042708

float:
173.3069458..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Expand on "does not seem to work" as that is the correct solution.

Comment: How do you cast the uint value to float. Do you use a static or a reinterpret cast?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991478/building-a-32bit-float-out-of-its-4-composite-bytes-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReadProcessMemory()` takes a pointer to void so it is up to you to point it at a `float`.

```
float f;
ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBaseAdress, &f, sizeof(f), NULL);
```

Note that this will break when `sizeof(unsigned int) != sizeof(float)`.

Casting won't work because it will take the value and not the representation of the integer.

Comment: +1, but why should it break when `sizeof(unsigned int)!=sizeof(float)`? We are telling to `ReadProcessMemory` to read exactly the size of a `float`, if the data read from the other process starts as a `float` (otherwise the whole thing wouldn't make sense :) ) it shouldn't break.

Comment: I don't think there is a sizeof problem on platforms where ReadProcessMemory actually exists. This code is not very portable, is it? :-)

Answer (score 4):

```
UINT d= 0x432D4E94;
float f= *(float*)&d; // 173.30695
```

Answer (score 4):

The safest way (that takes in account possible alignment problems) is to use a union

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    union FloatOrUInt
    {
        float asFloat;
        unsigned int asUInt;
    } fu;

    fu.asUInt = 1127042708;
    printf("Float value = %0.6f\n", fu.asFloat);

    return 0;
}
```

Note however that even if you know that floats are in standard IEEE754 format there can be problems for [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating-point_and_endianness).

Answer (score 2):

```
unsigned int input = 1127042708;

float output = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&input)
```

or

```
float output = *(float*)(&input)
```