# C++ Version Of Double.longBitsToDouble

Tags: c++

Does Anyone know the c++ version of java's Double.longBitsToDouble ... i have seen this answer which answers float.intBitsToFloat; [C equivalent of Java's Float.intBitsToFloat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30610222/c-equivalent-of-javas-float-intbitstofloat)

i tried to apply the same method to convert Java_java_lang_Double_longBitsToDouble to pure c++ version, but the function has a line i don't know how to convert, the line being `jlong_to_jdouble_bits(&v);`

you can find the class here https://github.com/openjdk/shenandoah/blob/master/src/java.base/share/native/libjava/Double.c

Comment: I tried but i'm not getting the same result as in java...

Comment: Read a good book about [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html) but be aware that C++ and Java are different language and might not have equivalents. Floating point is tricky, read http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: [searching for the definition](https://github.com/openjdk/shenandoah/search?q=jdouble_to_jlong_bits) indicates that its a macro that does nothing

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the content from long variable to double variable, here is the example:

```c
double ori_d_value = 3.14d;
long l_value = 1234;
memcpy(&l_value, &ori_d_value, 8);  // convert double value to row long value
double d_value;
memcpy(&d_value, &l_value, 8);  // convert row long value to double value
printf("long value: %ld, double value: %lf\n", l_value, d_value);
```

Comment: I am not sure it is not undefined behavior. Of course, on most systems, it will practically work but is implementation specific (endianess issues, implementations representing floating point outside of IEEE-754, such as IBM mainframes)

Comment: You should also check that both types have the same size, 8 bytes (likely, but not guaranteed). Also, if the the intent is to "play" with the bits of the internal representation, an unsigned type should be better.