# Does accessing the 4 bytes of a float break C++ aliasing rules

Tags: c++, floating-point, language-lawyer, endianness, single-precision

I need to read the binary content of a file and turn the extracted bytes into single precision floating point numbers. How to do this has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3991478). That question does have proper answers but I'm wondering whether a particular answer is actually valid C++ code.

[That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62724456) gives the following code:

```cpp
float bytesToFloat(uint8_t *bytes, bool big_endian) {
    float f;
    uint8_t *f_ptr = (uint8_t *) &f;
    if (big_endian) {
        f_ptr[3] = bytes[0];
        f_ptr[2] = bytes[1];
        f_ptr[1] = bytes[2];
        f_ptr[0] = bytes[3];
    } else {
        f_ptr[3] = bytes[3];
        f_ptr[2] = bytes[2];
        f_ptr[1] = bytes[1];
        f_ptr[0] = bytes[0];
    }
    return f;
}
```

Is this actually valid C++ code? I'm not sure whether it violates any aliasing rules.

Note that I'm targeting platforms with big endian where a float is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits long.

Comment: A safe approach is to `memcpy` from the byte array to the `float`.

Comment: You might want to add `language-lawyer` tag if you want the standard cited chapter-and-verse.

Comment: @Evg `std::bit_cast` doesn't work when the float is within a longer buffer that's not just that one float.

Comment: _Is this actually valid C++ code? I'm not sure whether it violates any aliasing rules._ It violates https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.add#6.sentence-1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this actually valid C++ code?

Potentially yes. It has some pre-conditions:

- `std::uint8_t` must be an alias of `unsigned char`
- `sizeof(float)` must be 4
- `bytes + 3` mustn't overflow a buffer.

You can add a checks to ensure safe failure to compile if the first two don't hold:

```
static_assert(std::is_same_v<unsigned char, std::uint8_t>);
static_assert(sizeof(float) == 4);
```

> I'm not sure whether it violates any aliasing rules.

`unsigned char` is excempted of such restrictions. `std::uint8_t`, if it is defined, is in practice an alias of `unsigned char`, in which case the shown program is well defined. Technically that's not guaranteed by the rules, but the above check will handle the theoretical case where that doesn't apply.

---

> float is guaranteed to be **at least** 32 bits long.

It must be exactly 32 bits long for the code to work. It must also have exactly the same bit-level format as was on the system where the float was serialised. If it's standard IEE-754 single precision on both ends then you're good; otherwise all bets are off.

Comment: C++17 and later also has `std::byte` (`enum class byte : unsigned char {};`) as another option that may better express intent / self-documenting code.