# Swapping Integers Efficiency

Tags: algorithm, swap

Simply,

```
X = Integer
Y = Another Integer

Z ( If used ,Integer Temp )
```

What's the most efficient method ?

**Method I :**

```
Z = X
X = Y
Y = Z
```

**Method II :**

```
X ^= Y
Y ^= X
X ^= Y
```

---

**Edit I**  [ *Assembly View* ]

**Method I :**

```
MOV  
MOV  
MOV
```

**Method II :**

```
TEST ( AND )  
JZ  
XOR  
XOR  
XOR
```

**Notes :**

- `MOV` is slower then `XOR`
- `TEST` , `JZ` is used for `XOR` Equality Safe
- `Method I uses extra register

Comment: Method 1. Trust your compiler; don't try to fool it. It'll do good things for you.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta This is not a LOW level concept ! Look as an assembly man, new register vs XORing ?

Comment: Don't believe me? Benchmark it, with -O3 or equivalent. Make sure you run a few gazillion iters.

Comment: By the way, I really appreciated the Rube Goldberg nature of Method III (since deleted).

Comment: @AhmedGhoneim: It's not a question of whether it's a low level concept, but just that it's a fact that compiler builders are very, very good at emitting the most efficient code for the target platform for this type of common operation.

Comment: I was just wondering by the way! Didn't know that this'll be annoying!

Comment: I think it's a very valid question to ask.  In fact, I often use that as an easy warm-up question when interviewing Engineers (not just how to swap, but various approaches and implications).

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/249469/445976) addresses why the xor "trick" is not necessarily a useful optimization. As always, profile your code on the target hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases, using a temporary variable (usually a register at assembly level) is the best choice, and the one that a compiler will tend to generate.

> In most practical scenarios, the trivial swap algorithm using a
>   temporary register is more efficient. Limited situations in which XOR
>   swapping may be practical include: On a processor where the
>   instruction set encoding permits the XOR swap to be encoded in a
>   smaller number of bytes; In a region with high register pressure, it
>   may allow the register allocator to avoid spilling a register. In
>   microcontrollers where available RAM is very limited. Because these
>   situations are rare, most optimizing compilers do not generate XOR
>   swap code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Also, your XOR Swap implementation fails if the same variable is passed as both arguments.  A correct implementation (from the same link) would be:

```
void xorSwap (int *x, int *y) {
     if (x != y) {
         *x ^= *y;
         *y ^= *x;
         *x ^= *y;
     }
 }
```

> Note that the code does not swap the integers passed immediately, but
>   first checks if their addresses are distinct. This is because, if the
>   addresses are equal, the algorithm will fold to a triple *x ^= *x
>   resulting in zero.

Comment: I think you're misinformed about instruction timing on modern processors.  See the link that @Blastfurnace provided in his comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/249469/445976

Answer (score 0):

Try this way of swapping numbers

int a,b;

a=a+b-(b=a);