# How to swap two dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have two dates in JavaScript, `start` and `finish`, parsed by [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). What would be the most efficient way to swap them if `start` is posterior to `finish` without having to create a third date? Typically, the dates would be parameters of a function like this one:

```
function getDates(start, finish) {
  var start_date = moment(new Date(start));
  var finish_date = moment(new Date(finish));
  if (start_date.diff(finish_date) > 0) {
    // Swap code goes here...
  }
}
```

The reason why one might want to swap dates is because some functions are defined in such a way that the same result is returned even if the dates are swapped, yet the function needs to know which date is the earlier one. For example, [YEARFRAC](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/yearfrac-function-HA102752812.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA102752955) in Microsoft Excel works that way. You can see my implementation of that function [here](https://gist.github.com/4567843) for an example of a sub-optimal date swapping.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You know you can literally get the MS time of a date, then set it in the other date, similar to (new Date().getTime()) then do set date on the other

Comment: Why can't you have a third variable? var x = start_date; start_date = finish_date; finish_date = x. This way you are not creating a _third date_, although I suspect, _third variable_ is what you meant. And if so why is that a constraint?

Comment: i don't know if you should go around swapping dates, unless one is unusually hotter than the other...

Comment: Just trying to be as efficient as possible. There are ways to do that for numbers with binary operators, and I was curious to learn if anyone had devised a way to do something similar with dates.

Comment: @thang, I added an explanation of why such swapping needs to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be the most efficient way to swap them if start is posterior to finish

With a third variable. For fun, you could use a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.7#Avoiding_temporary_variables) to <s>prevent that</s> work syntactically around that, but this will hardly make a performance difference.

> without having to create a third date?

That's the point of using a variable. With the [binary operator way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/249423/1048572) you mentioned you would need to cast the Date object to an integer, apply the operation, and then create *two new* Date objects from the integers.

Answer (score 1):

If your constraint against having an additional Date should be interpreted as not having another variable at all, then I have a solution based on [this person's brilliant idea for inline variable swapping](http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=265):

```
function getDates(start, finish) {
    var start_date = new Date(2013, 0, 5);
    var finish_date = new Date(2013, 0, 4);
    start_date = start_date.getTime();
    finish_date = finish_date.getTime();
    start_date = -(finish_date = (start_date += finish_date) - finish_date) + start_date;
    start_date = new Date(start_date);
    finish_date = new Date(finish_date);
    alert(start_date);
    alert(finish_date);
}
```

Comment: You do know that this sorts the dates by their string serialisation?

Comment: I get it, but this tells me that I might be trying to find a solution to a problem that does not really exist. A third variable might be all it takes, and anything else will be more complex and less efficient.

Comment: I've modified my response to remove the array solution. My second suggestion (still visible above) was more in keeping with your question anyway, and the comment by @Bergi led me to realize that there were aspects of the string serialization that I didn't take into account with the array sorting approach. The array solution could have been made to work with a minimal amount of additional code -- but since you've already acknowledged that a third Date is the best way to go, I've just removed the buggy lines rather than re-write them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to have understood what you need but, if you pass the timestamp to `start` and `finish`, with something like this:

```
start_date = start > finish ? finish : start;
finish_date = start > finish ? start : finish;
```

you swap the values without the third temporary variable. Then you can create the moment objects and work with them. For example:

```
function dateDiff( start, finish, measure ){
  var start_date = start > finish ? finish : start, 
      finish_date = start > finish ? start : finish;
  return moment(finish_date).diff(moment(start_date), measure);
}

dateDiff( new Date(2013,1,21), new Date(2013,1,28), 'days' ) // 7
dateDiff( new Date(2013,1,28), new Date(2013,1,21), 'days' ) // 7
```

If you need only to know the positive difference you can even do:

```
date_diff = (start < finish ? finish : start) - (start < finish ? start : finish);
```

**EDIT:**

However, it's possible [to test](http://jsperf.com/js-ternary-vs-if-else/3) that even with ternary operators the performance is lower than the classic `if..else` statement.

Hope this might be of some help.