# swapping two variables using bitwise opeation and not using a third variable in c

Tags: java, c#, c

i could do with third variable

```
c=a|b;
a=c&a;
b=c&a;
```

But i need to do it without third variable. I tried using XOR it wasn't helping me either.

Comment: Xor swap algo: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: Or perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249423/how-does-xor-variable-swapping-work

Answer (score 9):

it's an easy 1st year programming class question:

```
a = a^b;
b = a^b;
a = a^b;
```

Answer (score 6):

XOR has a property that XORing something twice always brings you back to where you started. You can use this fact to switch variables in three assignments without a third variable.

```
int a = 54;
int b = 23;

a = a XOR b; // (a XOR b)
b = a XOR b; // (a XOR b) XOR b = a
a = a XOR b; // (a XOR b) XOR a = b
```