# Working with pointer : pointer assignment to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

Here I have tried to make a function which may swap two values without a third variable. What other implementation might work to do so other than the one stated below?

```
void swap(int* x, int* y)
{
    (*x)=(*x)+(*y);
    (*y)=(*x)-(*y);
    (*x)=(*x)-(*y);

}
```

Comment: You need an xor swap algorithm. Please look it up on wiki

Comment: Your error messages aren't about this code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth what is wrong with the application? Why is the above code invalid?

Comment: It *is* valid, at least, it won't cause those error messages.

Comment: There are cases where the result of the operation overflows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does XOR variable swapping work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249423/how-does-xor-variable-swapping-work)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are trying to do the `XOR` [swap trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int* x, int* y)
{
    *x^=*y;
    *y^=*x;
    *x^=*y;
}
int main(){
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;
    swap(&x, &y);
    printf("x = %d, y =%d\n", x, y);
}
```

Comment: Nice example! Simple and concise

Comment: Note: Please don't ever do this in code.

Comment: It's OK to do in code if you use `unsigned int`.

Comment: Thanks @merlin2011 for introducing me to something new (atleast for me).

Answer (score 0):

it should work actually...

I used the following code with your function:

```
void swap(int* x, int* y)
{
  (*x)=(*x)+(*y);
  (*y)=(*x)-(*y);
  (*x)=(*x)-(*y);
}

int a1=1;
int a2=2;

main()
{
   swap(&a1,&a2);

   printf("a1= %d\na2= %d \n",a1 ,a2);
}
```

Comment: I had tried using the same code earlier but it didn't work well at that time but now it works fines. May be it was some interpreter etc issue. @Oli Charlesworth sorry for the inconvenience.