# Trying to count how many characters there are in a string in C

Tags: c, string, reverse

```
void reverse(char s[]) {
    int i;
    int len = 0;
    for (i=0; s[i] != '0'; i++) {
      len = len + 1;
    }
```

Here is my code above. s[] is the string I am trying to reverse; Please help! Thanks

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You're missing the last closing brace `}`, and did you actually have a question you wanted to ask?

Answer (score 5):

Use `'\0'` to test for the null terminating character.

```
for (i=0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
  len = len + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void reverse(char s[]) {
    size_t i,j;
    for(i=0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        ;
    if(i < 2)
        return ;
    for(j=0; j < --i; ++j){
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice and short.  (Although I'd suggest `size_t i,j;`)

Answer (score 1):

[There isn't a `strrev` in standard C](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/string.h.html), but there are many implementations available around the net.  Here's one I found [here](http://www8.cs.umu.se/~isak/snippets/strrev.c):

```
#include <string.h>

char *strrev(char *str)
{
    char *p1, *p2, c;

    if (! str || ! *str)
        return str;
    for (p1 = str, p2 = str + strlen(str) - 1; p2 > p1; ++p1, --p2)
    {
        c = *p1;
        *p1 = *p2;
        *p2 = c;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Note that this modifies the given string and performs the reverse in place.

Comment: That's a terrible abuse of the [XOR swap trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249423/how-does-xor-variable-swapping-work). Why not use a temporary variable and cut the number of memory accesses in half?

Comment: Well, as I said I found it on the interwebs. :)  You're right, it's entirely unnecessary. I'll edit to use a nice clean swap.

Answer (score 0):

`Strings` in `C` are just an array of characters terminated with the `null` or the `\0` character.

change your condition `s[i] != '0'` to that that checks whether the character at index `i` is of null or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
strrev(string1,string2)
```

in the string.h header. You can also use the

```
strlen(string1)
```

from the same header to find the length.