# Bitwise swap without XOR

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I need to swap two variables without both XOR and arithmetic operations.
All I can use are bitwise operations like ~, &, |, <<, >>, etc.

I understand the XOR approach, but can't figure out the other way around this..

EDIT: Temporary variables are not allowed either.

Comment: so can you replace xor(^) with a combination of &, | and ~?

Comment: @Fallen, Yes, I think I can. I was wondering if there is a fundamentally different approach, not just a replacing XOR with more basic operators and using XOR-exchange all over again. Maybe something allowing shifts or more novel combinations of operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [XOR is a combination of ANDs and NOTs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38473/21117), all you need to do is implementing it in Java:

```
static int nand(int a, int b) {
    return ~(a & b);
}

static int xor(int a, int b) {
    return nand(nand(a, nand(a, b)), nand(b, nand(a, b)));
}
```

With this implementation in place, you can [swap using XOR](https://stackoverflow.com/q/249423/335858).

Comment: But are you allowed to use a temporary variable?  I mean, if you could do that, you could just swap them directly.

Comment: So if you take the temporary variable out of this answer, you're left with `return nand(nand(a, nand(a, b)), nand(b, nand(a, b)));`.

Comment: @DM That's just for convenience - one can replace `nab` with a call to `nand(a, b)` in both places where it is used, and be done with it. Obviously, it does not matter anyway, because it's a learning exercise designed to teach students that XOR can be modeled with other operations.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Given your last comment, do you feel you have helped or hindered the learning of OP? Just asking... :)

Comment: @rici Helped, of course: I was taught this trick in a class on integrated circuits back in the eighties; good chances are, OP has not taken this class (I am not sure it's offered anywhere these days). I also think that this trick is about as useful as the knowledge of designing with vacuum tubes :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Definitely agree about the utility of the trick; indeed, it may be even less useful. But I sometimes wonder if we're underestimating the importance of figuring things out for yourself.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Thank you. I indeed didn't take a circuits classes and I appreciate your willingness to help.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the [answer of dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42183225/3182664), an `xor` can be emulated with `nand`, consisting of `not` and `and`. Analogously, the `xor` can be emulated with `nor`, consisting of `not` and `or`.

The expressions will look a bit complex in the end...

```
public class XorTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        testNand();
        testNor();
    }

    private static void testNand()
    {
        int a = 1234;
        int b = 5678;

        a = xorNand(a, b);
        b = xorNand(b, a);
        a = xorNand(a, b);

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    private static void testNor()
    {
        int a = 1234;
        int b = 5678;

        a = xorNor(a, b);
        b = xorNor(b, a);
        a = xorNor(a, b);

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }

    private static int xorNand(int a, int b)
    {
        return ~(~(a & ~(a & b)) & ~(b & ~(a & b)));
    }

    static int xorNor(int a, int b)
    {
        return ~(~(~(a | a) | ~(b | b)) | ~(a | b));
    }
}
```

But I can't think of a way that does the same "only" with shifts or other "novel combinations of operators" - whatever this should mean, exactly...