# Understanding a C++ function for reversing a string using ^=

Tags: c++, string, bitwise-operators

The code below returns a reversed string.  For example, it take input "`codebyte`" and returns "`etybedoc`".

```
string FirstReverse(string str) {
    for(int i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i < str.length() / 2; i++, j--)
    {
        str[i]^=str[j]^=str[i]^=str[j];
    }
    return str;
}
```

I am lost as to how this function works:

1. Why is the `^=`-operator being used? It is a bitwise operator but why is it being used here?
2. Why is `str.length()` divided by 2 in the for loop?
3. What is with the alteration of `str[i]` and `str[j]`?

I want to work though it with values but I don't know where to begin.  The introductory textbook I used did not cover this.

Comment: It's a swapping functionality similar to the famous bit-twiddling hacks.
The length is divided by two because otherwise you would undo every swap and end up with the original string again.

Comment: It's using XOR operator to swap the characters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm

Comment: I would flunk this code in code review. I'm not even sure it would work on every compiler as it seems like it might have the kind of order of evaluation dependency that the standard would say results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does XOR variable swapping work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249423/how-does-xor-variable-swapping-work)

Comment: @Omnifarious Absolutely, this is code by someone who thinks they're being clever but ends up writing bad code.

Comment: The right way to write that expression with all the `^=` in it is `::std::swap(str[i], str[j]);` .

Comment: Also the result of bitwise xor might produce a trap representation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an answer:

- It's a swapping functionality similar to the famous bit-twiddling hacks.

  - A detailed explanation of this swapping mechanism can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).
- The length is divided by two because otherwise you would undo every swap and end up with the original string again.
- The indices `i` and `j` run against each other (from the beginning or end, respectively).

Comment: For this to be anything like a good answer, you should explain the bit-twiddling.