# How to swap contents of two variables with one register (asm-simulator toy ISA)?

Tags: assembly

I am new in assembly
I tried to move variables in this link
https://schweigi.github.io/assembler-simulator/
I tried to change the content of char1 and char3

```
JMP start
char1: db "A"  
char2: db "B"
char3: db "C"
start:
    MOV A, [char1]
    MOV B, [char3]
    MOV [char3],A
    MOV [char1],B
```

now I want to do it only with one register ( without B )  , it is possible to define another variable
but i didn't understand  how to move the content between 2 variables
Could you please advise ?

Comment: You can use the `xor` swap trick but is not recommended.

Comment: How I can do it with 4 variables ? how I can move content between variables ?

Comment: @jester - How I can do it with xor ?

Comment: One way with a single register is to push `A` onto the stack.

Comment: @WeatherVane - is it possible to do with 4 variables ?

Comment: Push all except one onto the stack. Transfer the last one. Pop and store the others.

Comment: Related: [How does XOR variable swapping work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249423/how-does-xor-variable-swapping-work)

Comment: @weatherVane - could you show me an example ?

Comment: Do you have to use 1 register?  We don't need any registers (modulo stack pointer): `push [char1]; push [char2]; pop [char2]; pop [char1]`

Comment: @ErikEidt that's good, but the `pop address` isn't supported by the [instruction set](https://schweigi.github.io/assembler-simulator/instruction-set.html) (as in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vane

```
    JMP start
char1: db "D"  
char2: db "O"
char3: db "G"
start:
    MOV A, [char1]  
    PUSH A 
        MOV A, [char3]
    MOV [char1], A
    POP A
    MOV [char3], A
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the (not recommended) XOR method

```
MOV A, [char1]
XOR A, [char3]
XOR [char1], A
XOR [char3], A
```

A discussion of the XOR method is here:

- [How does XOR variable swapping work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249423/how-does-xor-variable-swapping-work)

Comment: Problem is, your simulator [instruction set](https://schweigi.github.io/assembler-simulator/instruction-set.html) doesn't have that addressing mode.