# Pythonic way of making xor test

Tags: python

What is the pythonic way to write the condition that checks that both variables cannot be none, and both variables also cannot be not None. For example

```
if a is None and b is None: raise SystemExit(1)
if a is not None and b is not None: raise SystemExit(1)
# rest of the code
```

Comment: Looks pythonic enough to me. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Are you using `pass` here because you have an `else` statement? In that case, why not use `if a is None or b is None:` for the opposite test?

Comment: @MartijnPieters If both `a` and `b` are None then I will raise an exception that this class needs atleast one of these arguments to run.

Comment: Then you want to check for `if a is None and b is None`, right?

Comment: @yayu: then your test is not correct. You'd use `if a is None and b is None: raise Exception`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're right checking if None is better. I am actually performing an xor test... only one among `a` or `b` can be `None` to pass, otherwise if both are None, or both are not None, it raises an exception. In the original problem I just wrote pass as a placeholder to keep the details out.

Comment: @yayu: then *make that part of your question*. As it stands it is just too vague to answer in any meaningful way and risks being closed as 'unclear', 'too broad' or 'primarily opinion based'.

Comment: This is now a duplicate of [How do you get the logical xor of two variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/432842); you can use `bool(a is None) != bool(b is None)` or `bool(a is None) ^ bool(b is None)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get the logical xor of two variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432842/how-do-you-get-the-logical-xor-of-two-variables-in-python)

Comment: Both variables cannot be none means one of them holds some value so `if (a or b)`

Comment: @BHATIRSHAD: `a = 0` is also a valid value, but `bool(a)` is `False`. An explicit test for `None` can have specific meaning you are ignoring.

Comment: You can use `if a : pass`

Comment: @d-coder: no you cannot. `a = 0` is not `None` but false in a boolean context.

Comment: @MartijnPieters `for a in None,0:if a :print "not empty"` would print the statement ?

Comment: why i this on hold? it is a stupid question, yes .. and a duplicate. but not unclear in any form.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a is None) != (b is None):
    raise SystemExit("kkthxbye")
# remainder of code
```

[What's the difference between XOR and NOT-EQUAL-TO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175480/whats-the-difference-between-xor-and-not-equal-to)

Answer (score -1):

You can try `if all((a,b is not None)): pass`

```
In [31]: a = 1

In [32]: b = 1

In [33]: all((a,b is not None))
Out[33]: True

In [34]: b = None

In [35]: all((a,b is not None))
Out[35]: False
```

**Note:**
Setting either of value of `a` or `b` to `0` will yield `True`

**Pythonic?**

```
In [36]: len('if a is not None and b is not None')
Out[36]: 34

In [37]: len('all((a,b is not None))')
Out[37]: 22
```

Comment: The OP wants an XOR test, e.g. **one** of the two **must** be `None`, the other **must not** be `None`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Did you get the question very well? The OP said `that checks that both variables cannot be none, and both variables also cannot be not None`.

Comment: The question is a lot clearer now than it was at the start, but do read the comments on the post. The OP is asking for an XOR operation.

Comment: And I think he edited the question. This wasn't what he asked originally.

Comment: You are only testing if both variables are `None`, not the inverse.